# Where does this code go in a Web Forms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to figure out where to put this code. I have tried placing it is the default.aspx.cs file but I am not for sure if I am putting it in the wrong portion of the template or not. Also, I have tried placing the aspx code in the default.aspx folder but I am having the same issue with that as well.

If someone can show me where this code is supposed to be placed that would be great!

Here is the code that I have:

**aspx code**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h1>Northwind Traders</h1>
<hr />
<br />
<div class="col-md-12 table-responsive">
<asp:GridView ID="ProductsViewID" runat="server" OnPreRender="Grid_PreRender"
PageSize="5" CssClass="table table-hover table-condensed" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="width: 100%;">
</asp:GridView>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**And here is the cs code**

```
public void LoadProductsData()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//We need to fetch data from Data Base we can call Fetch_ProductList() with
//necessary changes mentioned. Here i am considering MS SQL DB
//since Data base details are not provided i am creating Data Table manually.
  
//Creating columns
dt.Columns.Add("Product");
dt.Columns.Add("First Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Last Name");

//Adding Rows
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Almonds","Roland","Wacker");
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Beer","Soo Jung","Lee");
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Beer","Francisco","Perez-Olaeta");
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Beer","Karen","Tob");

dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Boysenberry Spread", "Run", "Liu");
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Boysenberry Spread", "Roland", "Wacker");

dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Cajun Seasoning", "John", "Rodman");
dt.Rows.Add("Northwind Traders Cajun Seasoning", "Roland", "Wacker");

//Assigning Data Table to Gridview
ProductsViewID.DataSource = dt;
//Binding the data to GridView
ProductsViewID.DataBind();
}

protected void Grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridView grid = sender as GridView;
try
{
if (grid != null && grid.Rows.Count > 0)
{

grid.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
grid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
grid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
}
}
catch (Exception)
{
}

}


public DataTable Fetch_ProductList()
{
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"); //Here we need to provide ConnectionString of Data Base.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
try
{
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//Here we need to provide the Query to fetch the data from DataBase
//Sample Query would be 'SELECT PRODUCT_NAME,[FIRST NAME],[LAST NAME] FROM NORTHWIND_TRADERS_TABLE'
cmd.CommandText = "HERE WE NEED TO PROVIDE QUERY";
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter reader = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
reader.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
conn.Close();
}
return dt;
}
```

Again, I am just needing help with the placement of the code. The code itself should work as intended. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Side note: I highly recommend you start with some basic "how to" tutorials. Especially for "legacy" code like this (aspx web forms is considered legacy by most developers) there are *many* tutorials and how to site out there to get you started so you can at least understand the framework basics. If even that is too much start with some basic c# tutorials before moving to web development. Finally if you have a choice as to what to learn first try learning some of the newer frameworks instead of the legacy ones like ... (continued)

Comment: ↑ ... - [asp.net core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc).

Comment: I have to ask- do you realize ASP.NET WebForms is old tech? If you are learning web development then you should [learn something modern](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro)

Comment: You're not "placing it in Visual Studio". You're doing a Web Forms project, and where the code goes does not depend on the IDE. The correct location would be the same if you were using Notepad, Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, vi, or any other editor. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Default.aspx should be a file, not a folder, even if VS shows default.aspx.cs below it

Comment: Well, while asp.net web forms are legacy? They ARE a technology designed to transition people from typical desktop development experience. Given that the newer technologies like MVC don't provide drag and drop designers? Then little wonder that asp.net developers are starting to wane in the marketplace.  So, web forms are STILL a great choice to introduce people from desktop experiences. And the learning curve to get up and running with asp.net webform is 1/10th the efforts required for MVC. So, if you force everyone down that MVC road - you going to wind up to killing the asp.net market.

Comment: As noted by others here? I would suggest a few basic video on how to use asp.net. The process is actually VERY similar to building desktop applications such as VB6, or vb.net. They are mostly a drag + drop type of process - and the same goes for asp.net forms. You drag a button, or a grid view. After dragging a button onto the form - you can double click on that button to write code behind.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Web Forms is dead. I've blogged about the reasons why [here](https://masonmcg.com/Blog/entry/stop-using-aspnet-webforms). It's not in the future of .NET. Everyone needs to have a plan in place to transition off of Web Forms. Doesn't really matter if you like it or miss the drag and drop experience - it will literally no longer be supported. People are not forced down the MVC road. There's Blazor, there's SPA + Web API etc. If someone is trying to learn a new framework and they don't have a very specific reason to do so, they should be warned. Glad Igor and Crowcoder spoke up.

Answer (score 1):

Web Forms has a couple places for this kind of thing, but probably you should look at the `App_Code` folder. You can put additional `*.cs` files in there with their own classes defined, including static classes.

Additionally, methods that fill a DataTable should *never* also directly update controls or set a data source. Instead, have the method (in this case `LoadProductsData()`)
return the DataTable as a value. Then, the ASP.Net Page Life Cycle event handlers will call into your method and use the result to update the controls on the page.

Finally, there's some code here leading me to believe you haven't yet been exposed to Sql Injection. Make sure you are **NEVER** using string concatenation to substitute user values into an SQL query. Instead, learn how to use parameterized queries. It's hard to understate how important this is.